# Why is Nhibernate SchemaExport unable to create a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate

I have the following code to generate the schema for a database in Nhibernate

```
new SchemaExport(configuration).Execute(true, true, false);
```

but when run against a PostgreSQL database, I end up getting the following error

```
[NpgsqlException (0x80004005): FATAL: 3D000: database "dbname" does not exist]
```

If I however create the database manually, the schema is exported without errors. An so the question: Why is Nhibernate SchemaExport unable to create a PostgreSQL database and yet this works against other databases like SQLite, MsSqlCe and MsSql Server.

I have searched for online literature but have been unable to locate any highlighting on this issue.

I am using Nhibernate 3.3.1 with PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new SchemaExport(configuration).Create(true, true, false);` ?

Comment: I think "*database "dbname" does not exist*" is pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *create the database* before you can create the tables and other objects within the database.

Do this with a `CREATE DATABASE` statement on a PostgreSQL connection - either in your app, or via `psql` or `PgAdmin-III`.

PostgreSQL doesn't support creating databases on demand / first access. Perhaps that's what your tool is expecting?

If you think the DB does exist and you can see it in other tools, maybe you're not connecting to the same database server? Check the server address and port.

Comment: I now understand. Thought I was making a mistake even though I could not see where. Any pointers to literature on "PostgreSQL doesn't support creating databases..."?

Comment: @CallMeKags Not off the top of my head / a quick search. It's difficult to do architecturally because PostgreSQL back-ends can't switch databases once started, and `CREATE DATABASE` requires a connection to an existing DB. There'll be more discussion somewhere on the mailing lists, but I can't find it at a quick search.